# how to check if a ul has a particular li with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on the two ul lists. What I need is if someone click on the list item in list1, it will check if the 2nd list contains the clicked element or not. If it does not contain the element then copy it else just return.

What I have done so far is I am moving the elements successfully between the list but if I apply a check on it everything stops working.

Here is the link of [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tumx8hty/).

```
$().ready(function() {
  var classHighlight = 'highlight';
  var $thumbs = $('ul li').on("click", function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    $thumbs.removeClass(classHighlight);
    $(this).addClass(classHighlight);
  });
  $('#select1').on("dblclick", "li", function() {
    //if($("#select2").has($(this))
        //return;
    //else
        $(this).clone().appendTo('#select2').removeClass('highlight');
  });
  $('#select2').on("dblclick", "li", function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  $('#add').click(function() {
    $('#select1.highlight').clone().appendTo('#select2').removeClass(classHighlight);
  });
  $('#remove').click(function() {
    $('#select2.highlight').remove();
  });
});
```

If you un comment the above lines in code everything stop working.
Can any one please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: No Rory it can be in both list at a time but what I mean is that if an item is already in list2 it can't be added again i.e the list2 can't contain any duplicate li.

Comment: Ah, ok that's clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this check:

```
var check = function(li) {
    return $("#select2 li").filter(function(i, li2) {
        return $(li2).text() == $(li).text();
    }).length > 0;
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tumx8hty/2/)

As you're using [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/), you can't compare the new cloned element using [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) or [`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) with the orignal one, because it is a new element, it isn't the same, as stated in `clone`'s docs:

> Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements

So it's a copy.

Comment: thankyou dear. It is working now. Can you please explain me another small issue in the same code?
You see after applying the clone method I am unable to select cloned the items from the list2 by clicking them. The only item I can select in list is option 5 which is by default in the list.

Comment: @BilalHussain [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/tumx8hty/3/). When you bind the event like `$("ul li").click()`, you're binding it to the existing `li` tree. If it changes the events will be gone, that is the case of the second list. But if you bind as `$("ul").on("click", "li")` you're binding to the `ul` instead, so doesn't matter how many `li` you add or remove, the event is bound to the `ul` so it will work with any `li`.

Comment: You are a life saver .Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing paren.

This `if($("#select2").has($(this))` should be this `if($("#select2").has($(this)))`.

Also you can just pass this: `if($("#select2").has(this))`

And you have to check length: `if($("#select2").has(this).length)`

Comment: Can you provide a working demo of this? I think when an element is *cloned*, the new element is not the same as the original.

Comment: You are right. Cloned copies are not equal to their original. I was just covering the missing paren.

Comment: Yes thankyou for pointing out the paran mistake but as you said they are not equal so its useless to use this method :)

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm leaving it because checking for a node is a more consistent method than checking for text depending on the situation. Like when two different nodes have the same text.